# geom_line to connect points based on two conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to connect only points that satisfy two conditions? For instance, if a point has a number value of 1 and a letter value of A, it will only connect to other points that have a number value of 1 and a letter value of A, and if a point has a number value of 1 and a letter value of B, it will only connect to other points that have those characteristics.

Comment: Yes, I think it is is if I understood you correctly. Can you give your try on the challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded a little example I hope this helps.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10), L=c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)),
       N=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2))

df <- transform(df, Group=paste(L,N,sep=""))

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x, y=y, col=Group, group=Group))+geom_point()+geom_line()
```

The idea is to create a Group column which tells ggplot which dots belong together. 
Cheers